# javascript countdown with getElementById

Tags: countdowntimer

I am facing a trivial issue with a code found on web that performs a countdown:

Uncommenting var minutes and seconds it works, but if I try to get minutes and seconds variables through getElementById the code does not work anymore.. why? any suggestion to correct this behaviour?

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
  var interval;
//var minutes = 0;
//var seconds = 2;



window.onload = function() {
   var minutes = document.getElementById("idtextmin").value;
   var seconds = document.getElementById("idtextsec").value;
   countdown('countdown');
   }

    function countdown(element) {
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            var el = document.getElementById(element);
            if(seconds == 0) {
                if(minutes == 0) {
                    el.innerHTML = "countdown's over!";                    
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    return;
                } else {
                    minutes--;
                    seconds = 60;
                }
            }
            if(minutes > 0) {
                var minute_text = minutes + (minutes > 1 ? ' minutes' : ' minute');
            } else {
                var minute_text = '';
            }
            var second_text = seconds > 1 ? 'seconds' : 'second';
            el.innerHTML = minute_text + ' ' + seconds + ' ' + second_text + ' remaining';
            seconds--;
        }, 1000);
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form>
Min<input type="text" id="idtextmin" name="textmin" value="2" />
Sec<input type="text" id="idtextsec" name="textsec" value="9" />
</form>

<div id='countdown'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your code **after** your HTML, `getElementById` won't find them because they're not yet declared. As alternative move them inside your `onload` function:

```
<script>
    // Declare them here, assign their initial value
    // in the onload event when HTML elements will be available
    var minutes;
    var seconds;

    window.onload = function() {
        minutes = document.getElementById("idtextmin").value;
        seconds = document.getElementById("idtextsec").value;
        countdown('countdown');
    }

    function countdown(element) {
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            var el = document.getElementById(element);
            if(seconds == 0) {
                if(minutes == 0) {
                    el.innerHTML = "countdown's over!";                    
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    return;
                } else {
                    minutes--;
                    seconds = 60;
                }
            }
            if(minutes > 0) {
                var minute_text = minutes + (minutes > 1 ? ' minutes' : ' minute');
            } else {
                var minute_text = '';
            }
            var second_text = seconds > 1 ? 'seconds' : 'second';
            el.innerHTML = minute_text + ' ' + seconds + ' ' + second_text + ' remaining';
            seconds--;
        }, 1000);
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form>
Min<input type="text" id="idtextmin" name="textmin" value="2" />
Sec<input type="text" id="idtextsec" name="textsec" value="9" />
</form>

<div id='countdown'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Tiutto see reviewed answer, copy & paste that code: it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are setting the minutes and second and again then setting it by get element id the is jumbling up code that u use.
Also try the javascript at end of the body. always leta the rendering complete then run script.

Answer (score 0):

put everything inside the window.onload function

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
<html>
    <head>

        <script>
            var interval;
            //var minutes = 0;
            //var seconds = 2;

            window.onload = function() {
                var minutes = document.getElementById("idtextmin").value;
                var seconds = document.getElementById("idtextsec").value;
                countdown('countdown');

                function countdown(element) {
                    interval = setInterval(function() {
                        var el = document.getElementById(element);
                        if(seconds == 0) {
                            if(minutes == 0) {
                                el.innerHTML = "countdown's over!";                    
                                clearInterval(interval);
                                return;
                            } else {
                                minutes--;
                                seconds = 60;
                            }
                        }
                    if(minutes > 0) {
                        var minute_text = minutes + (minutes > 1 ? ' minutes' : ' minute');
                    } else {
                        var minute_text = '';
                    }
                        var second_text = seconds > 1 ? 'seconds' : 'second';
                        el.innerHTML = minute_text + ' ' + seconds + ' ' + second_text + ' remaining';
                        seconds--;
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            Min<input type="text" id="idtextmin" name="textmin" value="2" />
            Sec<input type="text" id="idtextsec" name="textsec" value="9" />
        </form>

        <div id='countdown'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```